# Launching a single process and its relative activities

Tags: android, android-activity, process

I have a list of running process and I want to launch a single process and its relative activities when user clicks on the relative icon.

```
ActivityManager actvityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<RunningAppProcessInfo> procInfos = actvityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
```

I have this list of running applications. By using OpenGL I show an icon for each running application. I just want to know how launch an activity process in foreground when user clicks on the relative icon that I get in this way:

```
icon = pk.getApplicationIcon(procInfos.get(i).processName);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bring existing activity to Foreground](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11762215/bring-existing-activity-to-foreground)

Comment: I believe that you should use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningTasks(int) as this concerns only process that have activities, or better, only to the activity stacks. Then you can launch the top activity of desired stack to bring it to foreground

Answer (score 0):

Not every process is attached to an `Activity` so trying to open an arbitrary process doesn't really make sense.

Instead why not just get the launch intent for the package the process belongs to using `PackageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage (String packageName)`.

Then a call to `Context.startActivity(Intent i);` should be sufficient to start the App.